# Get list of records where only latest record from one table is selected

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, one-to-many

I have a couple of tables joined by associations, table Skew has records differing by the date when the data was added ( column "Updated").  I'm trying to query the tables to extract a list only for the most recent record in table Skew, not all records.

For example the line below correctly extracts the latest record and value A from table Skew.

```
double A = DATActx.Skews.OrderByDescending(B => B.Updated).
Where(B => B.DealContract == "AP-20-Oct-16").
Select(B => B.BookA).First();
```

The query below extracts all records, not just the latest.

```
var ListData = DATActx.Books.
                              OrderByDescending(B => B.Option.Skews.Updated).
                              Where(B => B.DealContract != null).
                              Select(B => new clsMonteCarlo.Leg()
                              {
                                  BookID = B.ID,
                                  DealNo = B.DealNo,
                                  DealContract = B.DealContract,
                                  BookA = B.Option.Skews.BookA        // one item in Book links to many in Skews - need to only select the latest record
                              }).ToList();
```

How can I modify the second query to only return the latest record in table Skew? The query below (and other variations I've tried) doesn't compile.

```
var ListData = DATActx.Books.
                              OrderByDescending(B => B.Option.Skews.Updated).
                              Where(B => B.DealContract != null).
                              Select(B => new clsMonteCarlo.Leg()
                              {
                                  BookID = B.ID,
                                  DealNo = B.DealNo,
                                  DealContract = B.DealContract,
                                  BookA = B.Option.Skews.BookA        // one item in Book links to many in Skews - need to only select the first record
                              }).First().ToList();
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
First().ToList();
```

This part doesn't make sense.  First() will return an instance of your Book class, which probably doesn't have ToList() defined.  Just remove ToList() and you'll get the record you want.

UPDATE

Based on your answer, you want an ordered groupby.

```
var ListData = DATActx.Books.
                              Where(B => B.DealContract != null).
                              Select(B => new clsMonteCarlo.Leg()
                              {
                                  BookID = B.ID,
                                  DealNo = B.DealNo,
                                  DealContract = B.DealContract,
                                  BookA = B.Option.Skews.BookA,
                                  Updated = B.Updated
                              }).GroupBy(g=>g.DealContract).Select(gr=>gr.OrderByDescending(b=>b.Updated).First());
```

Comment: That just gives me one record like a Take(1) extension. I need a list of records with the last record in Skew selected, not all of them. i.e. the second query returns 16 records instead of 8 because table Skew has two duplicate records (or different update dates)

Comment: Your question is literally "How can I modify the second query to only return the latest record".  So do you need 1 record, or a list of records?

Comment: I'll try and modify the title a bit. I'm looking for a list of records where only the latest record in table Skew is selected, not all of them. For example Skew contains records with the same DealContract, but different Update dates. Like a customer order table where the customer and products are the same but order date is different.

Comment: I tried making the title a bit clearer...Not easy to explain in one line.

Comment: Ok, if I understood you correctly, you have four records, Contract1 Date1, Contract1 Date2, Contract2 Date1 and Contract2 Date2, and you want to return Cotract1 Date1, Contract2 Date1.  Something like that, correct? If so, I've updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks - works exactly like I needed it to. I appreciate the help! Cheers.